# EmEditor Highlight row with matching symbol

Tags: emeditor

How can I make EmEditor highlight or mark a whole line when when there is a "£" symbol in the Second Column of that row.

Answer (score 1):

In the find dialog you can change the default "select all" to "bookmark all". A bookmark selects a whole line.
Does this help you?